# Is about me profile picture for reputation update later compare to top navigation?

Tags: support

I have seen many times, top navigation reputation is different than about me profile picture reputation.

Is it a bug or something related to my browser issue?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think it's by design: You're using flairs in your profile, which are only updated once every 24-36 hours.

> [image: screenshot]